# Break event untill click and after continue jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to break an event that i submitted and when it breaks a popup will come, after I click the button I understood then it will continue to the rest of the code to execute it.

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search_cerf").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.site-content-area').html('Some Stuff done');
    // Popup comes up and we stop here
    $('.container .site-content-area').append('<div class="popup-thank-you" style="display: block;"><h2>ERROR</h2><span class="message-popup">THE BIG MESSAGE</span><br><br><br><button id="gotit" class="gotitval">I understand. Please validate now</button></div>');
    // after users click I understood please validate now it shoul continue to next step
      $('.container').on('click', '.gotitval', function(event) {
        $('.popup-thank-you').remove();
      });
    // do some other stuff ajax related
    alert ('script had finished');
  });
});
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean or what the problem is.

Comment: I have a form and i am submitting the form, when i submit the form a popup message should appear and it should stop the running of the code until the user clicks ok.

Comment: You're thinking about this all wrong.  You don't want to "stop running the code".  What you want is for your code to respond to the events you want it to respond to.  If the `alert()` needs to happen after clicking on `.container` then it should happen in the click event handler for that.  The answer below demonstrates this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move you alert script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search_cerf").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.site-content-area').html('Some Stuff done');
    // Popup comes up and we stop here
    $('.container .site-content-area').append('<div class="popup-thank-you" style="display: block;"><h2>ERROR</h2><span class="message-popup">THE BIG MESSAGE</span><br><br><br><button id="gotit" class="gotitval">I understand. Please validate now</button></div>');
    // after users click I understood please validate now it shoul continue to next step
      $('.container').on('click', '.gotitval', function(event) {
        $('.popup-thank-you').remove();
        alert ('script had finished');
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, forgot to mentioned, I need it to work as alert function, I don't have any alert there.